# How do you decode a file encoded in Base64 in java back to it's original contents?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, base64

I'm writing a file uploader in Spring MVC and I am encoding a file into a Base64 string to send to a web service using:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(uploadItem.getFileData().getBytes());
```

The web service will send the encoded string back to me and I want to know how to regenerate the file from the encoded string. I know you can do this:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
```

but how do you change the byte array back into the file?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Where is this file? You want to send it in an HTTP response?

Comment: I'm not really concerned with where it is and how it is being sent. I was just wanting to know what to do with the encoded string when I get it from the web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the bytes to a file using `FileOutputStream` as in [this example](http://www.java-examples.com/write-byte-array-file-using-fileoutputstream).

Comment: Note that the example code can leak a file handle as it does not close in a finally block.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html):

```
//Java 7
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
  out.write(decoded);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). Note the [write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) method that takes a byte array.